# Upgrading React-router from 4 to 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to upgrade react-router from v4 to v5.  My app has the currently installed versions of dependencies.

- react-router@4.3.1
- react-router-dom@4.3.1
- react-router-config@1.0.0-beta.4
- react-router-redux@5.0.0-alpha.9

Is there a particular order that I should update these dependencies?  I also see that react-router-redux has been deprecated for the latest major versions of these dependencies.  Does that mean I should be removing react-router-redux first?

(From the react-router readme)
[image]

I tried upgrading react-router from 4 to 5, and ran into errors because I use withRouter outside of .  I tried upgrading react-router-dom first and ran into [this issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6492).  So far I have not seen anyone asking how to upgrade from 4 to 5, all posts I have found are for a v3 to v4 migration.

Comment: Any luck on this?

Comment: Yes!

First I bumped react-redux from 5 to 6.  This required me to replace react-router-redux with connected-react-router.  The migration guide to move to connected-react-router is [pretty simple](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/issues/74#issuecomment-443785454) 

Lastly, I upgraded react-router from 4 to 5 and react-router-config to version 5.  These two packages need to be the same version (5 and 5, or 4 and 4).  Let me know if you run into any problems.